# Footer doesn't take the height of the inside wrapper

Tags: html, css

Is there anybody who know the problem ?

css:

```
    footer {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background:black;
}
footer .wrapper {
    width:1000px;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    color:grey;
}
footer .wrapper .footer_column {
    width:333.3px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
}
```

HTML

```
<footer>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="footer_column">
            Content
        </div>
        <div class="footer_column">
            Content
        </div>
        <div class="footer_column">
            Content
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Thanks in advance

http://jsfiddle.net/cWCFV/

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want your footer to expand when the content in your footer_column div grows?

Comment: Yep indeed :) But I can't find out how

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grow height of parent div that contains floating nested divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463069/grow-height-of-parent-div-that-contains-floating-nested-divs)

Comment: This is a _"Please fix my code."_ type of question.

Comment: And why is it a "please fix my code" question? when i don't find out the problem by myself then i ask someone else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put overflow: auto; in your footer div.

```
footer {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:red;
    overflow: auto;
}
```